# Python Pandas: Drop rows based on NA but retain rows with NA meeting condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I want to drop NA values from, but there is a specific combination of two columns in which I expect NAs, so I want to drop all the NAs except those that meet that criteria, while retaining them.

E.g for the table:

| Index | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | log | petal |
| 2 | 2 | B | tree | leaf |
| 3 | 1 | A | NA | petal |
| 4 | 2 | B | tree | NA |
| 5 | 3 | A | NA | leaf |
| 6 | 2 | B | log | petal |
| 7 | 3 | B | NA | leaf |
| 8 | 3 | A | log | NA |

I want to drop all rows with NA based on that aren't [Col3 == 3] and [Col2 == A] and this exemption only applies to NA in [Col3].

Such that if `[Col1 == 3], [Col2 ==A], [Col3==NA], [Col4 != NA]` it is not dropped, but kept. But even if it is `[Col1 == 3], [Col2 ==A]`, but `[Col4 == NA]` the row is dropped regardless of what value [Col3] is.

In the above case, only row 5 is exempt from being dropped due to NA, as it meets the criteria  `[Col1 == 3], [Col2 ==A], [Col3==NA]` and `[Col4 != NA]`.
Although row 8 is `[Col1 == 3], [Col2 ==A], [Col3==log]`, because `[Col4==NA]` the row has to be dropped.

The final dataframe should look like this (retaining original indexes to illustrate dropped rows):

| Index | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | log | petal |
| 2 | 2 | B | tree | leaf |
| 5 | 3 | A | NA | leaf |
| 6 | 2 | B | log | petal |

The dropped rows all had `NA` in them, apart from row 5, which was expected to have `NA` at `[Col3]` based on its conditions from [Col1] and `[Col2]`, and still had a value in `[Col4]`.

I hope this makes sense.

So what is the best way to do it, as dataframe.dropna() will remove row 5, and assigning following dropping by filter, e.g dataframe = dataframe[(~dataframe[Col1]==3) & (~dataframe[Col2]==A)].dropna() will also likewise filter out row 5 to the new assignment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dropna doesn't work great for a complex set of rules to keep or remove NAs. It's really for just rapid, straightforward cleaning. Make your own index.

```
# Create a boolean index of rows to keep
# Use standard logical operators

# Throw away all the NAs in Col 3
keep_these_rows = ~pd.isna(dataframe['Col 3'])

# Make an exception for the Col1/Col2 exclusion
keep_these_rows |= ((dataframe['Col 1'] == 3) & (dataframe['Col 2'] == 'A') 

# Throw away all rows which are NA in Col 4
keep_these_rows &= ~pd.isna(dataframe['Col 4'])

# Index your dataframe with the rows to keep
dataframe = dataframe.loc[keep_these_rows, :]
```